# Dynamic declaration in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

is it possible to do dynamic declarations? 
I will explain: I have a table `COLUMNAMES`:

```
ID|Name
 1|Country
 2|City
 3|District
 4|Neighbourhood
```

For each record in that table I would like to do something like:

```
declare @i int = 1
declare @number int
set @number = (SELECT count(*) FROM COLUMNNAMES)

While @i <= @number
BEGIN
Execute ('Declare column' + @i +'varchar(25)')
Execute ('set column' + @i +' = (Select NAME from COLUMNAMES where id = ' + @i)
set @i = @i + 1
END
```

The idea is that I get a list of variables (strings) that I can use to create SELECT statements with dynamic table-aliases:

```
 Execute ('Select SOMECOLUMN as ' + @columname +  @i +', ANOTHERCOLUMN as ' + @columname +  @i +', ATHIRDCOLUMN as ' + @columname +  @i + ' FROM SOMETABLE')
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not complete solution but a direction . you need to get the value **'SomeColumn'** dynamically someway ,likely the way you are getting the aliases in the below solution.

```
declare @i int = 1
declare @number INT
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)=''
DECLARE @ColumnsWithAlias VARCHAR(4000) = ''
set @number = (SELECT count(*) FROM COLUMNNAMES)

   While @i <= @number
  BEGIN

Select @ColName= NAME from COLUMNAMES where id =  @i)

SET @ColumnsWithAlias =@ColumnsWithAlias + 'SomeColumn'+ ' AS '+ @ColName + ' , '

   set @i = @i + 1
   END

   SET @SQL= 'SELECT '@ColumnsWithAlias+' FROM  TableName'

  EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `Execute` function as a different session.

So, in order to declare the variable, all the code must be in one `Execute` function.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't declare variables like this, but you can use a temporary table with the data filled in.

Here is some help, but it is not a whole solution, just an idea what you can do instead of the not working declaration:

```
    Create Table #ColumnNames(
        NAME varchar(64) 
    )
    While @i <= @number
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO #ColumNames
       Select NAME from COLUMNAMES where id = @i
       set @i = @i + 1
    END
DECLARE @Columns varchar(max)
SET @Columns = ''
SElECT @Columns = @Columns + NAME + ', ' 
FROM #ColumNames
```

Comment: How do you mean Andras? Like, create a #table(columname + @i, NAME FROM COLUMNNAMES)  and then use that to create the dynamic columnames?

Comment: I prefer to be pointed in the right direction, instead of being spoon-fed ;) I will look at this, learn from it and implement this. Thank you András

Comment: i don't understand the purpose of Temp Table @Columns variable can be filled directly from the original Table.

Comment: True, but I just showed because I don't know exactly what he needs.